# java design by contract

Tags: java

Why

1) **you can test postconditions with assertions in both public and non public methods**

but, you are advised to

2) **not use assertions to check the parameters of a public method(preconditions)**?

I understand that 2) is caused by :
- convention: the method guarantees that it will always enforce the argument checks(e.g. with checked exceptions) so it must check its arguments whether or not the assertions are enabled.
- the assert construct does not throw an exception of the specified type. It can throw only an AssertionError, which is not quite user friendly

But I don't understand why 1) is available for public methods as well ?

Thanks.

**The above questioned rephrased** :)
A contract is made of two parts :

```
- requirements upon the caller made by the class
- promises made by the class to the caller
```

Why Sun advises you to not use assertions as preconditions for public methods because the assertions could be disabled and then you are not checking the requirements imposed on the caller, but allows you to use assertions to test postconditions for public methods(test the return value to see you are returning a correct result) is still an enigma for me.

Put in other words, you must be very careful when enforcing requirements, but you can close an eye when verifying the promises.

Is there a **technical reason** for this metaphorically called "lack of ethics" that you demostrate when you enforce your client to respect the requirements, but you are not so harsh with yourself in respecting the promises ? :)

Comment: Good related discussion.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276308/exception-vs-assertion  I don't see any reason why assertions should be disabled in production code.  If correctness is an objective, and the (usually small) performance impact is acceptable, assertions will provide excellent feedback in the event of an unexpected condition or programmer error.

Answer (score 2):

Point 2) states you shouldn't use assertions because they might not be turned on.  Instead, it appears to recommend using checks which are performed every time and throw a checked exception.

If you want to throw different exceptions when assertions are enabled you can do

```
boolean assertions = false;
assert assertions = true;
if (assertions && myCheckHere) throw new MyExceptionOrError();
```

Technically, a method has parameters e.g. String name, a method is invoked passing *arguments* e.g. "Hello", So its the argument you want to check, the compiler will check the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You are using "assert" keyword to assert your assumptions and in case of public methods the pre-conditions should be always true (so that the method has correct data to perform its task) whether running in production or not.

Since assert will be **disabled** in production you can't use the assert keyword to enforce the pre-conditions of a public method so you should be throwing a unchecked exception. Now, coming to the post-conditions there is no such contract for the method (say f1) performing the task. The output of this f1() method might be a input to another method (say f2), in which case the pre-conditions in f2() might enforce the assumptions.

On a side note, I suggest looking at the [google-guava library's Preconditions](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) class for checking pre-conditions and throwing unchecked exceptions, both using a simple and intuitive API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is useful, although I want to bring a short amendment: the return value is contained by the contract as much as the parameters of the method are, so the preconditions and postconditions are important for respecting the contract in equal proportions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you got this information, but assertions are excellent for checking the parameters of public methods. They enforce the very contract that the method claims to live up to.

Comment: It is from the Java Tutorial here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/assert.html#postconditions

Comment: To summarize: it's better practice to throw a specific exception if the inputs to a public method are wrong, and one that isn't disabled by default. This is where Meyer differs from the rest of the world. Java's designers say that calling a public method with bad arguments is dangerous, and the method itself should check that it didn't happen. But with real DbC, you don't check contracts, you specify them, and perhaps the language checks them. Less code is written, responsibilities are always clear, and hopefully the code scales better.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a technical reason but a reflection of the fact that asserts aren't a design by contract implementation, which is something they say in the guide.

> On balance, we came to the conclusion that a simple boolean assertion
>   facility was a fairly straight-forward solution and far less risky.

Not everyone sees things the way that Meyers does, and Java has language goals which conflict with Eiffel's in some places. In *Program Development in Java*, Liskov stresses defensive programming, that is, if something can go wrong, contract-related or not, you check for it as you go. Contracts are "asserted" in comments that go at the top of the method body. Now, that book predates the addition of boolean asserts to Java, and who knows what they would have said if it had been written a couple of years later. My point is that

- more than one treatment of contracts exists
- asserts are primitive and probably best used where they're practical, instead of trying to do real DbC with them

As you noted, the designers suggest that you could do some DbC with postconditions, nonpublic preconditions, occasional invariant checks, but they don't sound all that serious about it. Is it unethical? I understand the objection, but it's not a given that everyone will want to program with contracts in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Java assertions are worthless, in my opinion.

If you read Meyer's "Object-Oriented Software Construction", he makes the case about how assertions should always be enabled - *especially* for production code. So, if they were always enabled by default, no matter what, it would be much better. Maybe I'm niggling with that fact a bit too much, but it's definitely a detriment - a static method is "safer"  since you know it will always execute... and you can still control that with a system property. thus the default is always 'safe mode'.

DbC - It seems kind of like it would be hard to fit into the Java language - we can't put preconditions/postconditions on an interface and have them automatically work on any implementation. There are some frameworks that attempt to provide this behavior, but I haven't managed to use them in any of my projects.

I instead write my own "Contract" class full of static methods, and use a lot of assertions throughout the production code. It has methods called 'precondition' and 'postcondition', but really all you care about is assert(). there is no mechanism in Java's design whereby you can implement 'pre' and 'post' hooks on an inheritor's code. that's why some of the frameworks out there use a precompiler or AOP...