# assertion failed to work in try catch block in selenium TestNG

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below code failed to report an error:

```
@Test
public void test() {

    int a = 12;
    int b =20;

    try {
        assertEquals(a, b);
    }catch(Throwable t){

    }
```

The code ran successfully and did not report any error. However, it was suppose to report an error as a!=b . If I don't use try catch block then it did report an error. Don't know why assertion is not working in try catch block. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assertions in Java are built on top of Java exceptions and exception handling. When a Java assertion fails, the result is an AssertionError exception that can be caught like any other Java exception. Hence, when you put assertion in try-catch block and catch the exception thrown by assertion, the execution continues. Please refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276308/exception-vs-assertion) for more details about Java Assertions and Exceptions. Let me know, if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are using

```
catch(Throwable t){

    }
```

Instead, if you use

```
catch(Exception e){

    }
```

Your code should work fine.

Check the explanation here : [Difference between using Throwable and Exception in a try catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274102/difference-between-using-throwable-and-exception-in-a-try-catch)